# Port is removed from URL on enter

Tags: php, url, port

So I just installed Dolphin Pro, and I was able to use `http://localhost:8080/dolphin/install/index.php` just like the instructions say.

Great! It says it's installed. However, when I try to go to:

`http://localhost:8080/dolphin/administration/` to get to the admin panel, when I hit enter to go, the url drops the port and I get the error message:

```
Cannot GET /dolphin/administration/
```

On the url: `http://localhost/dolphin/administration/` (notice the port :8080 has been dropped!)

I'm using chrome, and XAMPP is running on port 8080, while my nodeJS server is running port 80.

I checked the processes with `netstat -aon` but that didn't help me.

Any idea why the port is dropping and I can't reach the URL?

[image]

Here is a `CURL` request to the URL

```
C:\Windows\system32>curl -I "http://localhost:8080/dolphin/administration/"
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Tue, 13 Oct 2015 14:18:54 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.16 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1p PHP/5.6.12
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.12
Location: http://localhost/dolphin/administration/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

More notes: It seems (as per @rlemon) that when I try using :8888 just as a random port, the port is NOT dropped. So there seems to be an issue with port 8080 forwarding to port 80

Comment: port 8080 will be default loaclhost port. So when you run it will remove from URL as well

Comment: can you try http://127.0.0.1:8080/dolphin/administration/ ?

Comment: I thought port 80 was the default. When I drop the port, I am hitting pages from my node server

Comment: IIRC Chrome does some stupid port checks; since 8080 port is not valid, it redirects to somewhere else.

Comment: @ogres localhost is a synonym for that local IP I think. Regardless, same effect.

Comment: @smar, what do you mean port 80 is not valid?

Comment: @SterlingArcher it was typo, I meant 8080 :) If I read correctly, you’re binding it to 80, not 8080, so there’s nothing listening on 8080, right? So not invalid in that way, but just closed.

Comment: try `curl -I "http://localhost:8080/dolphin/administration/"`

Comment: @SterlingArcher just run `localhost:8080/` and check

Comment: Guys, I am 100% positive both ports work. I installed Dolphin via :8080, and I have another system running on :80

Comment: `302 Found` means a redirection, so maybe the daemon running on that port does redirection to :80 port address? Does it have some kind of hardcoded domain in its config which it gives as URL?

Comment: Do other browsers do the same?

Comment: @Abdulla *"port 8080 will be default loaclhost port."* This is utter nonsense. Please remove your comment before someone else starts to believe this delusional statement.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. It seems more suited for [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The server answers with a 302 redirect.

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://localhost/dolphin/administration/
```

These two lines basically tell the browse to go to the URL provided.

Check the configuration of your server, there must be a way to set the base url where you have to provide the port.

Looking through [the FAQ of Dolphin](http://www.boonex.com/trac/dolphin/wiki/GenFAQ#HowcanIenableSSLsupportinDolphin) I found this config file entry:

```
$site['url'] = "http://example.com/";
```

Adding the port there should solve your problem

```
$site['url'] = "http://example.com:8080/";
```

There seems to be a second relevant line:

```
header( "Location:http://{$aUrl['host']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}" );
```

Again, add the port after the host:

```
header( "Location:http://{$aUrl['host']}:8080{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}" );
```

Not sure if it works in this line though, it depends if the first `/` is in the host or the REQUEST_URI variable, you have to try it.

Comment: That stopped the port dropping thanks! Unfortunately it's throwing a redirect loop, so I'll have to figure that out next. Thanks for you help

Comment: Hey, you should add this line to your answer, since it caused a redirect loop. By default, this if statement is routed to port:80 `if ( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) and 0 != strcasecmp($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $aUrl['host']) and 0 != strcasecmp($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $aUrl['host'] . ':8080') ) {` on line 95 in header.inc. Change it to the proper port, and installation is a success.

Comment: If you modify PHP files of the application directly you will have to repeat these edits after every update you make. In the long run you should consider to change your setup. The usual configuration is to have apache on the default port 80 and redirect requests to the application server (in your case node.js) which runs on an alternate port. It will save you a lot of work in the future.

Comment: That will be the case for production. It's only different ports atm because it's being locally run along side another local server -- hence 2 ports.